# how can i do interpolation with multi language in react native using i18n

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

**Question:**

I have an `i18n.ts` file and a `translate.ts` file that I am using for multi-language support in my application. Currently, I am using the `translate` function with a key and an array containing `I18n.locale` set to the user's selected language as the only argument. However, I also want to be able to use interpolation in my translations. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Here's an example of my current usage:

```
translate('hello', [
                    (I18n.locale = auth.language),
                  ])
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!